# Caffe Embed Layer Inputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, word-embedding

What type of input does the Embed layer in Caffe take?
Does it take words already encoded in one hot form?

Suppose, N = number of words in input sentence ; M = vocabulary size

Then one hot vector for a single sentence will be of order N x M

Does this mean the the input dim parameter will be N?

Lastly in what format should the sentences be saved so that Caffe embed layer can read it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the documentation of [`"Embed"`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1EmbedLayer.html#details) layer:

> A layer for learning "embeddings" of one-hot vector input. Equivalent to an InnerProductLayer with one-hot vectors as input, but for efficiency the input is the "hot" index of each column itself.

Therefore, your input is not a "hot vector" representing a word (or a character, or an "item") but rather a compact representation of the word: an integer index of the word in the disctionary.

So, if you have `M=1000` words in your dictionary and you want to learn an embedding into 100 dimensional space:

```
layer {
  name: "embed1000_to_100"
  type: "Embed"
  bottom: "compact_one_hot_dim1000"
  top: "embed1000_to_100"
  embed_param {
    num_output: 100 # output dimension
    input_dim: 1000
  }
}
```

Note that the data of `"compact_one_hot_dim1000"` should be integers in the range (0..999).

See [caffe.help](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/embed.html) for more information.